# Using the notation of families to denote vectors

Tags: notation, terminology

Is it common to use the notation for families in the context of vector spaces? For example, is it common to write $\{x_i\}\in R^n$? Alternatively, is there any other similar notation that avoids writing $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in R^n$?

Comment: $\{x_i\}\subset R^n$, or just $x_i\in R^n$.  What you wrote is wrong: the set of $x_i$ values is not an element of $R^n$.

Comment: Something like $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ might be an appropriate notation

Comment: I am using the notation for families presented by Halmos in his book "Naive Set-Theory". Halmos writes "An unacceptable but generally accepted way of communicating the notation and indicating the emphasis is to speak of a family $\{x_i\}$ in $X$, or of a family $\{x_i\}$ of whatever the elements of $X$ may be; when necessary, the index set $I$ is indicated by some such parenthetical expression as ($i \in I$). Thus, for instance, the phrase "a family $\{A_i\}$ of subsets of $X$" is usually understood to refer to a function $A$, from some set $I$ of indices, into $P(X)$.

Comment: I don't know if it is common in mathematics generally, but I think it must be common in the works of Bourbaki and his collaborators, because it is used quite extensively in the appendix on linear algebra in Dieudonne's *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, and, somewhat less systematically, in Godement's *Algebra*, e.g. to define matrices, and infinite linear combinations of elements.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the expression $\{x_i\}\in\mathbb R^n$ is meaningless. $\{x_i\}$ is a singleton, i.e., a set with one element, which is $x_i$. This set cannot be an element of $\mathbb R^n$, since $\mathbb R^n$ contains tuples, i.e. elements of the form $(x_1, \dots x_n)$.

If you want a simple way of denoting an arbitrary element of $\mathbb R^n$, you can simply use $x$, and it is usually implicitly accepted that $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$.

Comment: I agree that $\{x_i\}$ without any other condition should be interpreted as a singleton, but I wrote $\{x_i\}\in R^n$. The set $R^n$ is the set of all n-tuples. In set theory n-tuples are defined using families; a family $\{x_i\}$ is a n-tuple if the family's index set has $n$ members.  I explained the notation for families in another comment.

Comment: @Angelos To me, $\{x_i\}\in\mathbb R^n$ sounds undefined unless you defined $i$ before-hand. It's not a singleton, because $i$ is undefined, and therefore $x_i$ is undefined, and it is not a family, because the index set is undefined. So yeah, to me, it's a nonsensical expression. And completely unnecesary complicating of the issue, since $x\in\mathbb R^n$ conveys what you want just fine, and is what most other mathematitians would use.

Comment: The index set is $n$, which makes sense in set theory. However,  if it is generally accepted to write $x\in R^n$ and having $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ implicitly defined then that is much neater.

Comment: @Angelos $n$ is not a set, it's a number. The index set is $\{1,\dots, n\}$. And sure, it "makes sense in set theory", but if you are dealing with elements of $\mathbb R^n$, you are more likely doing either analysis or linear algebra, and it's easier to use shorthands that all or at least most other people use in the same situation. If I see $x\in\mathbb R^n$, and later on $x_i$, I will assume that we are talking about the $i$-th component of the vector $x$, if no other things point otherwise.

Comment: @ 5xum A number is a set in mathematics founded on set theory. However, you may choose whatever foundation you want. I understand your point and I agree that one should use a notation that is most widely accepted and understood by the peers of one's field.

Comment: @Angelos I was 99% sure you'll go with the "everything is a set!" argument, and let me just give you a piece of advice: don't. Don't, especially when arguing with any real mathematitian (which I am not). It is one of the few sure ways to annoy the living crap out of them. It deranges the argument, while at the same time doing nothing to address the actual point of the argument.